# notifying Adapter from Service, adapter refreshes but ListView doesnt?

Tags: android, adapter

I'm experiencing a strange problem with my ListView, I'm trying to update my LisView from a service.
My adapter is static and so is my ListView, when I Call notifyDatasetChanged(), I can see my adapter working, but my ListView does'nt refresh itself.
I tried to use eventManager, Handler(), Handler with Main Looper, runOnUiThread from the EventManager, all of them same result, but when I use any of those methods from the Fragment itself (which contains the ListView), it works perfectly:

```
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {                                   


            @Override
public void run() {


                //Refresh View if its CurrentView
                if(NotificationsManager.CurrentView.equals(SplittedName)){
                    SingleChat.adapter.notifyDataSetchanged();

                    System.out.println("Adapter Notified");
                }
```

And this is my adapter:

```
 adapter = new      
ChatAdapter(MainActivity.MAcontext,android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, 
aCursor,headers,new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2}, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Appears I wasn't calling `Cursor.requery`.
Doing so fixed the issue.

Answer (score -2):

Try find a way to remove cache. Mine worked.
 MainApplication.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache().remove(url);

Comment: You might want to offer an explanation to your answer. I would help the OP and others to have a clearer understanding.

Comment: I wish I could. I'm not a professional. I'm just suggesting to find a way to remove cache. Mine worked.